# Ion-button (click) event not working in Modals - Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, click, ionic3

I'm working with Ionic 3 on iOS 11. Ever since upgrading to iOS 11, my buttons don't work inside Modals. Specifically speaking, the (click) events don't trigger:

HTML:

```
  <button ion-button (click)="logoutUser()">LOGOUT3</button>
```

JS:

```
  logoutUser() {
    console.log('Logout the user');
  }
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: Yes, all that done, it was a silly mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add a z-index to the outer most box in which your button resides.

Comment: what do you mean by z index, please explain the answer in a clear way, so that every one can understand. Without a code just write a sentence doesn't make the answer.